# Assistance with JSON changing page contents dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am working on a website and I am looking to make the recipes pages dynamic. I created a JSON test database, created a JS file that retrieves values from the JSON file and displays them in appropriate divs on the page.

What i want to do is be able to choose the respectful JSON for each recipe and display it on the same page when a user clicks a link in the sidebar without having to create a ton of blank HTML pages with the same divs.

Below is my code. Hoping someone can help guide me thanks!

```
(function() {

'use strict';

 var url = 'my json url';

 $.getJSON(url, function(json) {

     //store json data into variable 
     var data = (json);

     //store data in empty string
     var title = '';
     var image = '';
     var directions = '';
     var prep = '';
     var cook = '';
     var serve = '';

     //retrieve values from dataArray   
     $.each(data[0], function (i, item) {
         title += '<h1>' + item.recipeName + '</h1>';
         image += '<img src="' + item.imageURL + '">';
         directions += '<p>' + item.directions + '</p>';
         prep += '<strong>' + item.prepTime + '</strong>';
         cook += '<strong>' + item.cookTime + '</strong>';
         serve += '<strong>' + item.servInfo + '</strong>';
     });

     //append results to div
     $('#recipeTitle').html(title);
     $('#recipeImage').html(image);
     $('#recipeDirections').html(directions);
     $('#recipePrep').html(prep);
     $('#recipeCook').html(cook);
     $('#recipeServes').html(serve);

     var ul = $('<ul class="nav nav-stacked">').appendTo('#recipeIngredients');

     $.each(data[0][0].ingredients, function(i, item) {
         ul.append($(document.createElement('li')).text(item));
     });

 });
```

})();

new code`(function() {
     function callback(json){

```
 //store json data into variable 
 var data = (json);

 //store data in empty string
 var title = '';
 var image = '';
 var directions = '';
 var prep = '';
 var cook = '';
 var serve = '';

 //retrieve values from dataArray   
     $.each(data[0], function (i, item) {
         title += '<h1>' + item.recipeName + '</h1>';
         image += '<img src="' + item.imageURL + '">';
         directions += '<p>' + item.directions + '</p>';
         prep += '<strong>' + item.prepTime + '</strong>';
         cook += '<strong>' + item.cookTime + '</strong>';
         serve += '<strong>' + item.servInfo + '</strong>';
     });

     //append results to div
     $('#recipeTitle').html(title);
     $('#recipeImage').html(image);
     $('#recipeDirections').html(directions);
     $('#recipePrep').html(prep);
     $('#recipeCook').html(cook);
     $('#recipeServes').html(serve);

     var ul = $('<ul class="nav nav-stacked">').appendTo('#recipeIngredients');


 $.each(data[0][0].ingredients, function(i, item) {
     ul.append($(document.createElement('li')).text(item));
 });
}

$('#pasta').click(function(){
  $('#recipeIngredients').empty();
  //get the url from click coresponding to the item
  $.getJSON(url,callback);
});

//intially load the recipies with the URL 
var url = '';
$.getJSON(url,callback);
```

})();`

Comment: All you've shown us is some code...but no problem statement, mention of errors or asked any question. We have no idea what is working and what isn't

Comment: theres nothing wrong with the code. i just want to learn how I can change page contents dynamically with the code I have provided. I want to create a single recipe page and change the recipe (from say pasta to pizza) on the same page without having to create multiple html pages. I have each recipe in the json file but I am not sure how I can show different content based on the recipe clicked left on the sidebar. thanks

Comment: so you need that to be called inside a click event handler. The element clicked would determine what url to use or what parameters to pass to server.  How are these recipes stored?

Comment: i have the recipes in a json file set up like this [ [ { "recipe" "recipe1" } ],   [ { "recipe" "recipe2" } ] ]   thats pretty much how my json is set up. nothing special just have all the contents for each recipe seperate by arrays. and then they all populate on the html page in each div

Comment: so you would need to load all the json when page loads and store it. Then filter it based on element clicked

Comment: do you think you could provide me with an example? im pretty new to this stuff but it sounds like I just need to store the json as a cookie in the browser and then access the data based on what element is clicked in the list?

Comment: No you would store the array in a variable. Read up on how to filter and/or search a javascript array

Comment: thank you for your help will read up on this

Answer (score 0):

to achieve code reusability , try calling the $.getJSON() with a reusable function (callback) on click of the link in the sidebar

```
(function() {
     function callback(json){

     //store json data into variable 
     var data = (json);

     //store data in empty string
     var title = '';
     var image = '';
     var directions = '';
     var prep = '';
     var cook = '';
     var serve = '';
    ....     //rest of the code
    ...
     $.each(data[0][0].ingredients, function(i, item) {
         ul.append($(document.createElement('li')).text(item));
     });
    }

    $('.sidebarLink').click(function(){
      $('#recipeIngredients').empty()
      //get the url from click coresponding to the item
      $.getJSON(url,callback);
    });

    //intially load the recipies with the URL 
    var url = 'my json url';
    $.getJSON(url,callback);

})();
```

Comment: make use of   $('#recipeIngredients').empty() to empty your curent recipe list elements on click before appending

Comment: how can i get it to know what recipe to load based on the click of the sidebar?

Comment: you can view my current code at the top with your example. just not sure how I can get it to grab certain data based on click